# How to generate Test Case Report from Xcode

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, xctest, xcode-server

I'm using default XCTest test framework to write and test application & I could able to do that. But to generate Test-Case report I'm not seeing any option except [Xcode Server](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH1-SW1). Is there any other way to generate Test Case Report!! Any Suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

when u run your test, a report is generated in

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectname/Logs/Test/TestSummary.plist
```

there you will get your all test information. But if you want a html format report you have to use

```
xcpretty.
```

let me know if you want to use xcpretty for html report or u can do your job using the TestSummary.plist

Comment: Hello @noor Can you help me out to generate the report using XCPretty?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your tests using [fastlane/scan](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/scan), an HTML report will be generated at the end of each test run as standard. It will open automatically in your browser when the tests are finished unless you tell it not to.

Scan is an easy way to simplify your test runs and make them configurable. The report is generated by [xcpretty](https://github.com/supermarin/xcpretty).